# Position Fixed Element is Shifting on Scroll

Tags: html, css

Hamburger icon is position fixed. When scrolling down the icon moves up a few pixels before stopping. When scrolling up the icon returns to its original position. I cannot find the cause of this bug.

**HTML**

```
<div class="rdi__menu-btn">
    <i class="open">menu</i>
    <i class="close">close</i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.rdi__menu-btn {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
div.rdi__menu-btn i {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

The issue seems not to be with the fixed element, but instead SquareSpace injected `.sqs-block {padding-bottom: 17px}` which is causing the page to scroll slightly even when content does not overflow the page. Weirdly, this is not happening with my prior projects on the platform.

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you accidentally zoomed in and you have x-axis scroll?

Comment: @AndrewSavetchuk No I'm not zoomed in. If you visit the "live classes" page which should not be scrollable, it is still shifting. I'm updated the post as I've seem to have found the culprit.

Comment: Thanks! I found a problem, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what causes a problem, if you remove it from your CSS problem gone.

```
.sqs-layout > .sqs-row {
    margin-left: -17px;
    margin-right: -17px;
}
```

Or if you want to keep margins you can add overflow-x: hidden property to your .sqs-layout class:

```
.sqs-layout {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden;` is a good option. Is still a hack, but I'll take it!

Comment: @RyanPrentiss I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

In your `head` tag, change

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

for

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

Then, disable and enable the device toolbar again to check it.
Sometimes a more complete viewport `<meta>` tag is required in order to some properties work properly.

Comment: `user-scalable-no` is a fix, thought I've never needed this in other projects. There has to be a bug somewhere. I'll use this as a last resort. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. And that's weird, I used a lot of fixed property before and never saw this bug.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I guess Create React App may not have the best viewport <meta> by default. This seems to have solved my issue.